# Stopping a Timer in python

Tags: python, timer

I'm making a little gag program that outputs a bunch of random numbers onto my Ubuntu terminal until the number meet a certain condition, at which point `access granted` is printed.

However, I'd like to stop the Timer loop once that condition is met, and I don't know how.

Here's the code below:

```
import random
import threading

def message():
    tt = threading.Timer(0.125, message).start()
    num = str(random.randint(137849013724,934234850490))
    print(num)
    if num[3] == "5" and num[6] == "7":
        print("access granted")

message()
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work as desired.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and consider doing the same for all your previous questions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timer` objects call their function *once* after a delay, that's it. The reason there's a "loop" is because the function you're telling the timer to call is what's setting up the next timed call to itself. So all you need to do is NOT do that once your condition is met:

```
def message():
    num = str(random.randint(137849013724,934234850490))
    print(num)
    if num[3] == "5" and num[6] == "7":
        print("access granted")
    else:
        threading.Timer(0.125, message).start()  # <== moved
```

Comment: Oops, this comment was intended for the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a threaded timer for that. Just loop an appropriate quantity of random numbers with a delay:

```
import time
import random
for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(1,10), flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```